# How do I update two columns in a database using datasets and datatables

Tags: c#

I want to update two columns in my database table.

Below is the code that I use to iterate through a datagrid to get addresses of shops.
In my database which I use to search for GPS coordinates using the method GetGoogleSearch.

I then get the GPS coordiates from the internet and I put them in a datatable.

I now want to update the columns and put that data I found and update columns as they are currently set to NULL for the coordinates Longitude and Latitude in the database.

Code is below for iterating and getting GPS coordinates is below.

Collapse | Copy Code

```
private void btnMapStoreAddresses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    AddressServiceData _AddressServiceData = new AddressServiceData();

    try
    {

        DataTable _PnPStoresListDataTable = new DataTable();
        string address = string.Empty;

        int GridRowCounnt = 0;
        GridRowCounnt = dgrgPnPStores.RowCount;


        for (int i = 0; i < GridRowCounnt; i++)
        {
             address = dgrgPnPStores.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            _PnPStoresListDataTable = _AddressServiceData.GetGoogleSearch("", address + " South Africa", "", "");             


        }

}
```

Comment: You might want to use a [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx). It might fit to your scenario and allow you to both populate the grid and update the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Dataset before you can work with the rows and / or tables.
This link might help;

[C# DataSet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714)

This link also has a decent example;

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714

Although - as Alex says, using SQLDataAdapter would most likely be best.

Comment: I am not sure how to carry on as I am not sure how to do it

Comment: How to do it - follow the first link; (tutorial link)
How to setup each element needed - 2nd link (look for the heading "Complete Code Listing (WebForm1.aspx)")

However, if you are starting from scratch and would prefer doing it the "correct" way - then i would suggest using the SQLDataAdapter route (googling "C# - using SQLDataAdapter" would put you in the right direction.)